# mod_rewrite duplicates html elements hence breaking the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mod-rewrite

I'm so not sure what's happening but I recently tried the mod_rewrite to modify my url.

The original url is this: **main/index.php?board=announcements**

I turned it to this: **main/board/announcements**

**Important note:** There is no announcements folder or file. I'm using it as a URL parameter for a query.

I used this line in my .htaccess file to modify the url:

```
RewriteRule ^main/board/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) main/index.php?board=$1
```

The problem is that it duplicates the page's html elements when I perform an action that does an ajax call such as posting a message or replying to the message. When I inspected the elements, it showed that my header up to the footer was duplicated (e.g. two head elements, two navigations) as if the whole html page is duplicated.

When I checked the Console, it also generated this:

```
jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
```

This isn't happening when using the original url, main/index.php?board=announcements. I don't know what is happening, really.

Here's my latest troubleshoot thanks to Wesley:

An example of one of my ajax call

```
$(document).on("click", ".like i", function() {
var postid = $(this).closest("div").parent().find("input").val();
$.post("like.php", {
userid: id,
postid: postid
}, function(data) {
alert(data);
});
});
```

And here's the content of the like.php

```
<?php echo "Hello"; ?>
```

For some reason, it is returning the whole HTML content! This isn't happening when using the original url. What could be the reason?

[image]

Comment: Can you show the JS you're using to load the new html from the ajax code and the php code that sends back that response? I feel like the issue  will most likely be there. Probably in the way you and the html in the JS, maybe using `append()` when you want `html()` or similar

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question with my latest troubleshoot based on your comment. I think I'm near the answer, but yeah. I provided the Ajax Code and the PHP although they weren't my actual codes (I did some troubleshoot). For some reason, it's returning the whole HTML content when using the data callback even though the PHP is only supposed to return "Hello". This isn't happening when the page is opened using the original url, only on a url modded by mod_rewrite.

Comment: Got the answer! Thanks for the tip. That helped me a lot. XD

Answer (score 0):

After 1-2 hours of troubleshooting, the problem lies with the url of the php file in the ajax call when a mod_rewrite is set. I checked over 15 threads about this and nothing mentioned about the mod_rewrite breaking even the path of an ajax url. But, there were some answers from the past threads that say the entire html returns only when the url is not existing. I didn't think it was wrong because the Console Log didn't say that it couldn't find the file.

Anyway, the fix is to set the absolute path of the php file.

Here's the exact url to fix the problem: **/main/like.php**